# Eclipse project reference C

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, eclipse-cdt

I have two projects in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and each has a folder with its libraries.

I want to include a header file from the first project to a library of the second project without typing something like:

```
#include "../../first_project_name/lib/Mylib.h"
```

I just want to type

```
#include "Mylib.h"
```

I tried to go to preferences of the second project at section project references and check the first project but nothing happend. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Includes** and add the correct include path.

Comment: tool settings -->avr compiler-->directories ? cause i can't see just includes inside tool settings

Comment: i have problem with linker when i go to add the name for the library. it give me an error that it can not find the folder.I give the name of the folder that the lib folder is inside.

Comment: @kyrpav I guess 'directories' are the same thing. You should also add the library search path (**Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> _Compiler_ Linker -> Library Search Path**) and the library itself (**Same as before -> Libraries**)

Comment: my problem  is that i have only .cpp and .h file.Library name is a file with extension .a so linker have problem.What do i do for this

Comment: As I said add the path where the .a file is located (Library Search Path), and then add the name of the library itself (without the 'lib' and '.a').

Comment: propably i can not explain correctly.There is no .a file. I inlude in my project a header file from another project.In order to do this i added the .h file path to the avr compiler and i get error from the linker.It is not a library it is the cpp file i have to link.

Comment: If you just need to add another object file to your project, copy it. You could also create a symlink if you don't want to copy each time.

Comment: You should also consider creating a library file out of the first project instead of relying on several object files. It's the common and accepted way of creating a 'library project' and having another project depend on it.

Comment: hmmm. i will try to found out how to create a library.if you know any tutorial that can help please it would save me time

Comment: also what about this symlink?

Comment: I'm not familiar any specific tutorial. I think it's pretty straightforward with eclipse (just create a shared/static library project) but I'm sure there are useful resources somewhere on Google. Type `man ln` to learn about symlinks (if you use Linux).